# How to make custom bump maps

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm working on a bathroom interior, and I figured that one of the main things I need is to have a good drywall bump map. I've looked around online to see if there are any good drywall type bumpmaps, but I haven't found anything good/free to use.  Is there anyway that I can create a convincing bump map that looks something like this image (in Cycles):

[image]

(Ignore the towel holder). It's okay if it's tile-able, but it needs to be big enough so that it doesn't look repeated.  If a similar effect can be achieved through procedural textures, I'm all for it.

Comment: I think GIMP has something like that

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Okay, I have GIMP.

Comment: Get a good image texture, and go to *Filters > Map > Bump Map*. *Make Seamless* is in the same place as well if you want that

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Okay.  By "Get a good image texture", do you mean take a picture of my wall?

Comment: Sure! An image of the type of wall you want to replicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you have a high resolution image of the wall you want to replicate. I'm going to be using [this texture](http://cgtextures.com/texview.php?id=98551) from cgtextures.com.

The best way that I know of for this, is to import it into gimp, crop it to a 1:1 aspect ratio:
[image]

You then use the make seamless filter to get this result:
[image]

Then import it into Blender and use the bump node to generate a normal map.
[image]

*Please note that this is how I like to setup a material, but the only important parts are the image texture and the bump nodes.*

Comment: Okay, my problem is finding a high resolution image.  Thanks for the help!  I'm thinking I might just go semi realistic and use a procedural texture...

Comment: I would recommend doing it procedurally if you can, not tiling then

Comment: Okay, just updated with images.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Okay.  Can you think of any good procedural setups?  Thanks!

Comment: A procedural texture is definitely a good idea if you can get it to work. If you haven't already, check out Bartek Scrupa's Blender Conference video on working with texture coordinates. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0